# How does I should calculate memory usage?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I have to implement an algorithm that can handle the main memory while executing, I write this function to read data from a file and as I was trying to compute the amount of memory used by this function I had some doubts.

```
struct point *load_dataset(char *filename, int dimension, int chunk_size, int start_idx) {

    struct point *dataset = malloc(chunk_size * sizeof(struct point));

    if(dataset == NULL){
        printf("Something went wrong in load_dataset(), memory allocation failed!");
        exit(1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < chunk_size; i++) {
        dataset[i].values = malloc(dimension * sizeof(double));
        if(dataset[i].values == NULL){
            printf("Something went wrong in load_dataset(), memory allocation failed!");
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    FILE *file;
    file=fopen(filename, "r");
    if (file == NULL){
        printf("Something went wrong in load_dataset(), file opening failed! (row 162)");
        exit(1);
    }

    char *line = NULL, *token;
    size_t len = 0;
    int i = start_idx - 1 ;
    int j = 0;
    bool end = true;

    while ((getline(&line, &len, file)) != -1 && i < chunk_size + start_idx) {
        if(i != - 1) {
            end = false;
            printf("line* size: %lu\n", sizeof(*line));
            while ((token = strsep(&line, ",")) != NULL) {
                printf("token* size: %lu\n", sizeof(*token));
                if(j == 0)
                    dataset[i].id = atoi(token);
                else
                    dataset[i].values[j-1] = atof(token);
                j++;
            }
            j = 0;
            i++;
        } else{
            i++;
        }
    }

    fclose(file);

    if (!end)
        return dataset;
    return NULL;
}
```

I considered utill before the `fclose()`:

1. `char *filename, int dimension, int chunk_size, int start_idx` in function declaration: `sizeof(char*)` + 3 * `sizeof(int)`
2. `struct point *dataset = malloc(chunk_size * sizeof(struct point))` : `sizeof(truct point*)` + `chunk_size` * `sizeof(struct point)`;
3. `FILE *file; file=fopen(filename, "r")`: `sizeof(FILE*)` + `sizeof(FILE)`;
4. `char *line = NULL, *token; size_t len = 0; int i = start_idx - 1 ; int j = 0; bool end = true`: 2 * `sizeof(char *)` + `sizeof(size_t)` + 2 * `sizeof(int)` +`sizeof(bool)`.

My doubt is how to treat `char* filename` as well as `char* len` and `char* token` (point 1 and 4), and `FILE *file; file=fopen(filename, "r")` (point 3).

Edit
I have to write an algorithm that can read from a file as many points as free main memory there is. Can someone provide me documentation about this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Assembler output will give an indication of how much memory is allocated for the stack frame.
2. Malloc allocates memory on the heap.
3. That depends on the implementation but it is very likely that the system will allocate much more memory (for example for i/o buffers or internal data)
4. Same as point 1. It is not easy to tell the exact value by looking at the code. It depends on the optimizations (some of those variables might be kept in registers only or optimized out completely etc etc)

Comment: I have to write an algorithm that can read from a file as many points as free main memory there is. Do you which is the right approach? Can you link me some documentation about that?